# x86 memory alignment

Tags: x86, 8086

For the 8086, unaligned word loads (first byte at an odd address) require two memory accesses, but an aligned word (first byte at an even address) can be loaded in one. This is excellently explained by answers over at Electronics Stack Exchange: ‘[Accessing odd address memory locations in 8086](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/498591/accessing-odd-address-memory-locations-in-8086)’.

How has alignment changed with later processors, particularly with the introduction of 80386 and x86-64? Does byte/word/double word/quad word alignment versus misalignment have any latency differences on later x86 processors? A lesser question but still of interest, does the bus high enable (BHE) pin still exist on modern x86?

Comment: This is very much CPU-specific, but the alignment penalty generally comes from having to do extra memory accesses. On modern x86-64, RAM is read in entire cache lines (64 bytes, usually) and so as long as the access doesn't straddle a cache line boundary, there is usually no penalty. But that's modern CPUs and this is RCSE. Do you have any particular retro x86 CPUs in mind?

Comment: Are you confusing 'instruction' with 'memory access'?  In many CPUs, a single unaligned load/store results in two read/writes to memory.

Comment: Yes, this ought to be clarified before people start rushing FGITW answers.

Comment: Also keep in mind that x86 is the odd CPU when it comes to alignment: Other CPUs (also "later" than 8086) have much stricter alignment requirements, and just don't allow unaligned memory access, so it's up to the compiler to properly align everything, or generate code that deals with unaligned access.

Comment: For x86 as recent as x86-64, see [How can I accurately benchmark unaligned access speed on x86\_64?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45128763) (my answer there covers some of the effects you'd want to look for with benchmarks).  All x86-64 CPUs have cache, so often the only penalty is from cache-line or page splits, or crossing some sub-line boundary like 16-byte or 32-byte.  See also   [What's the actual effect of successful unaligned accesses on x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12491578)

Comment: Also related: [Are there any modern CPUs where a cached byte store is actually slower than a word store?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54217528) (yes) re: modern x86 CPUs being designed to extract / insert data efficiently at any alignment within a cache line, unlike many non-x86 CPUs where that takes an RMW of the containing word if it's not fully written.  (So for example, byte stores are worse throughput unless store coalescing of adjacent ones can make a full-word (or ECC granule size) write.  Even CPUs without unaligned load/store like @dirkt mentioned usually still have byte load/store.)

Comment: For that last, re: byte stores on various ISAs and what the semantics are (in terms of being thread-safe), see also [Can modern x86 hardware not store a single byte to memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46721075)

Comment: @another-dave if you are referring to the same as Raffzahn's first three paragraphs (thanks), then you are correct and I misunderstood. For misaligned word accesses on the 8086 there is one instruction but two memory accesses. The 8086 Primer p13: The program in the 8086 is oblivious to all of these memory-accessing contortions; an instruction merely requests the accessing (reading or writing) of a particular byte or word, and the processor does whatever is necessary to perform such an access.

Comment: @pndc not any particular processor necessarily. More trends on how misalignment has changed particularly in terms of latency. Going to 32-bit, so the 80386, may well change the example of requiring two memory accesses for a misaligned word? Current understanding (confirmed by Peter Cordes' link "Can modern x86 hardware not store a single byte to memory?") is that due to factors like cache, most modern x86 processors can access a misaligned word at the same speed as an aligned word, thus historically what were the factors / trends that made this possible?

Comment: Also related re: evolution of x86 bus widths is the evolution of atomicity guarantees: [Why is integer assignment on a naturally aligned variable atomic on x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36624881) - P5 Pentium (still purely a 32-bit CPU) and later guarantee that 64-bit aligned load or store are atomic.  On P5, that's only doable via x87 FPU `fild` or similar, but that's still better than `lock cmpxchg8b`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It depends on the CPU.

A 386SX has a 16-bit bus, so loading a double word would need to access only two or up to three memory addresses to load a double word. It would have a BHE or equivalent to load only high byte or full memory word.

A 386DX has a 32-bit bus, so loading a double word would need to access only one or up to two memory addresses. It would not have a single BHE equivalent, because each memory address is four bytes, so it would have four Byte Enable lines to load a byte, a word, or a double word from the 32-bit bus, or a part of it if a word or double word is loaded from un-aligned address.

A modern X86-64 would not be retro any more.

Answer (score 6):

> For the 8086, unaligned (first byte is odd) word loads require two instructions, but an aligned (first byte is even) word can be loaded in one instruction.

Sorry, but that's wrong. It will be one instruction in either case, as loading a 16 bit value is the same single instruction, no matter if it's pulled from an even or odd address.

What reading a 16 bit word from an odd byte address in a 16 bit wide memory system requires is that this single instruction has to do two byte fetches. Two memory cycles (each two clock cycles) will get issued.

> How has alignment changed with later processors, particularly with the introduction of 80386 and x86-64?

Sorry, but beside that asking for today's CPUs isn't on topic, it's as well a way too wide area - Intel alone produced CPUs bearing any thinkable combination of factors, plus there were/are [more then two dozen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_x86_manufacturers) other x86 manufacturers as well.

> Does byte/word/double word/quad word alignment versus misalignment have any latency differences on later x86 processors?

This depends on a multitude of factors (which is rather a generic CS question, isn't it?)

- access type
- memory width/used CPU bus width used
- alignment in relation to memory width
- cache line size
- alignment in relation to cache line size
- All of the above multiplied by cache levels.

So pick your favourite CPU and try again :))

> A lesser question but still of interest, does the bus high enable (BHE) pin still exist on modern x86?

Again, asking about modern is by default off-topic - and as well, any combination of bus size signals you may think of have been made. So better check the data sheet of either CPU you're interested in.

Comment: AMD64 exist since 20 years, not exactly today.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_x86_manufacturers . In particular, Cyrix, Transmeta, NEC, and TI.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 RC.SE is about stuff no longer used. AMD64 is still used today. Well, except for the fact, thet AMD64 is _not_ a bus implementation, which the question is about, but an instruction set. Instruction sets doe (usually) not define how physical access is done, just logical.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123: There have been various x86 clone vendors over the years (like Cyrix and Transmeta being some of the later 32-bit examples), but far fewer x86-64 vendors. Just AMD, then Intel, and Via.  And apparently Zhaoxin continuing Via's design.  Building an x86-64 that can meaningfully compete with modern OoO exec CPUs is a much bigger challenge then it used to be.  (And probably patent-encumbered if Intel managed to patent anything about decoding x86 to uops in their P6 design that came out in ~1995, so their patent-sharing agreement with AMD probably keeps the market closed.)

Comment: I mention this primarily because the question said "80386 and x86-64".  I assume they meant literal 80386, since they used the full chip number, not just the i386 32-bit ISA, but Raffzahn probably assumed they meant 32-bit x86 in general.  Not that it narrows it down enough; different vendors use different busses, and vendors sometimes change busses between generations.  (Especially when Intel changed from an FSB to integrated memory controller in Nehalem.  https://www.realworldtech.com/nehalem/).  Not that busses are really relevant for most code, because caches exist.

Comment: @PeterCordes except that the question is rather about the effect of data orientation (and width) vs. bus width (internal and external) is. Those effects prevail even with caches. the main issue here is that they are extreme hard to pin down in an environment of caching, generic prefetch, instruction related prefetch as well as staged execution. After all, modern Chip designs are less about peak performance, as smoothing out single effects - including misalignment.

Comment: @PeterCordes Regarding 386 and AMD64, it seems as if the OP thought they would have been the only changes in bus deign as they mark an obvious inclusion of 32 and 64 bit data types, but 32 (and larger) data types have been used before. Likewise the memory word already went 64 bit with the Pentium - plus the ability to run either 3/486 or Pentium running with different RAM word sizes (yes, Pentium can run without much hassles from 8 bit memory :)) So despite using a mixup of chip and architecture names, it's all about bus interfaces and should be taken as such.

Comment: @Raffzahn: I wouldn't call the data path between a core's load/store execution units and its own L1d cache a "bus".  And regardless of misalignment, a load on a WB memory region either touches a cache line or it doesn't, resulting in the whole cache line getting pulled in or not.  So alignment isn't directly relevant to external busses like the DDR4 bus, except for uncacheable accesses.

Comment: As far as microbenchmarking it, ya some obscure effects; see my answer [here](//stackoverflow.com/q/45128763).  Notably, uop replays were something BeeOnRope and I got wrong initially; we were testing with `mov rax, [rax]` and stuff like that, and thinking that the line-split load itself was replaying for that reason, but actually it's any dependent uop that will get dispatched in anticipation of the data arriving that cycle, and having to get replayed if L1d didn't produce the full result (because of misalignment or mis-speculation about skipping address calculation before TLB lookup...)

Comment: @PeterCordes _"And regardless of misalignment, a load on a WB memory region either touches a cache line or it doesn't, resulting in the whole cache line getting pulled in or not. "_ Well, yes, except, depending on alignment it can always touch _two_ cache lines resulting in two pulls when continuing over the end of a cache line, thus the same effects as with external bus are as well happen with internal busses. Arguing about further details in that area will be extrem model and design specific, so far from what would makes sense for a basic (and generic) answer, wouldn't it?

Comment: Right, I was talking about per-cache line not per-load.  So a single load, the external bus eventually sees zero to two requests for whole cache lines, depending on misses in various levels of cache. Modern CPUs can already track multiple in-flight cache lines to get some memory-level parallelism, so the only special things with a split load happen inside the load port, not on external busses. (Assembling the two sides of the split load when they arrive, e.g. Intel CPUs having a limited number of split-load buffers in a load port and there's a perf event for load execution blocking on lack of)

Comment: @Raffzahn If it is only stuff that is no longer used, you can't ask questions about Windows 98 (We still use it productively in our company for some task that doesn't work on newer systems). I am pretty sure you will find nothing to discuss here.

Comment: "Two memory cycles (each two clock cycles) will get issued." That's true for the 80286 and 80386. On the 8086, a memory cycle takes four clock cycles, so a misaligned 16-bit access requires 8 clocks.

Comment: @MichaelKarcher Jup, you're right.